# Sorting firestore collection before and after limiting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the last 1000 items from firestore and then sort them in ascending. So I tried

```
  connection()
    .collection(`somecollection`)
    .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
    .limit(1000)
    .orderBy("timestamp")
```

Having **orderBy** twice doesn't seem to work. But works with one **orderBy**
I know I could do this in client but is it possible to run this am I missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to orderBy by ascending, as it is by default.

```
connection()
.collection(`somecollection`)
.limit(1000)
```

**EDIT:**

Firestore doesn't support the functionality you are looking for, so you need to query the initial data in a descending order, and the on client [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it in the way you need

```
connection()
.collection('somecollection')
.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')
.limit(1000);
```

Comment: But I need to sort the collection in descending and then limit them to 1000 and then sort the limited value in ascending

Comment: I've updated my answer as I didn't understand your question at first glance